# Not able to store bitmap in specified location in android.xamarin

Tags: android, file, bitmap, xamarin.android

I'm looking to store that `bitmap` in physical location, this is my code, no `Error` no `Exception`,not getting that image,
Any need is helpful.

```
public void Downloads()
{

        Bitmap bm = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("https://bsujournalismworkshops.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/jpg.png");

        try
        {
           var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath,"jpg.png");
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
     bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string Exe=e.ToString();
        }

    }       
public Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
        try
        {

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please try add `stream.flush()` before `stream.close()`. And please make sure you are checking the correct folder of your device/emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the write permission in manifest[image]

Comment: You've to uninstall and debug it again it worked for me.